# insert into Teradata using R JDBC

Tags: database, r, jdbc, teradata

I am using R JDBC and teradataR to connect R to teradata.  I would like to write a table using the function dbWriteTable, but am receiving this error

[Error 3932] [SQLState 25000] Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.)

This works perfectly fine using RMySQL on a MySQL database.

There is a similar thread here where the problem was believed to be the lack of a 'begin transaction', but turned out that wasn't the case
http://forums.teradata.com/forum/extensibility/teradata-r-create-table-based-on-a-data-frame-using-jdbc

Comment: Can you post the SQL or code that you are submitting? What value is the `TMODE` parameter set as for the JDBC connection to Teradata?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a DDL statement alongwith DML statements during parallel execution (; semicolon on the next line) or in ANSI mode, and the DDL statement is not the last statement in the block, you will get this error.

```
select * from employee
;create table dept as select * from tmp_dept with no data
;update table employee set name = 'abc' where id = 101;
```

As you observe, DDL will result in implicit commits; while in a transaction either the entire transaction is committed else rolled back.
I think you now get the intuition.
Please check if removing the DDL code and only using DML solves the problem